# Update excel from access shuffles rows

Tags: excel, import, rows

We have an access 2003 database and an excel 2003. We connected the excel to import the data from the access, so far so good.
At the end of the imported data right to the next 3 fields of the excel we want to add some comments, text.

Up to here all work fine, but when we update the data to excel the rows shuffle and the comments at the right columns remain at the same row. So the data rows shuffle and the comment rows remain at the same position.

So if row 3 has at the right the comment 3, when we update the worksheet to retrieve the new data from access it replaces row 3 with data from another row but the comment remains at row 3.

Is there a way for the excel to keep the imported data to the same position and not shuffling it?

We tried all the options at excel "What to do when new lines of data are available" but all do the same, it shuffles the data when we update, even if access has no new data.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will find that when you imported data from Access, Excel created/named a range called 'database' or 'data' or something like that. You need to expand that definition to include the added columns.

Comment: I did some tests with excel 2007 and the above works. It does not shuffle the rows and also the suggestion from gssi works OK. But the excel must work with 2003 version, which has the above problems. The reason that we want to use excel 2003 is that the access database is 2003. Is there a way to connect excel 2007 or 2010 to access 2003? When we tried to to this it gave us errors.

Comment: I suspect the errors may be due to file format changes. Did you try opening the 2003 version and then re-naming and re-saving it using the 2007 or 2010 Access program?

Comment: Another approach might be to setup the comments in another table which links to the imported table via the primary key field. Then the comment data can be restored using an INDEX-MATCH retrieval formula.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I think that it was the sorting we chose at the access. The sorting was by date at access and whenever we did update data to the excel inserted new rows at the middle. Now the sorting at access is by date and by ref number so every new row will be added at the bottom, when we hit the update button. Unfortunately we do not have a unique id at the access, that would be the best option for sorting..